# nginx fails to load static .mp4

Tags: nginx, video, mp4

**The Setup**

- I am aiming for a minimalistic configuration, mostly built on defaults
- The goal is to serve 10-15, 1-to-3 second long, mostly 2-3 Mb of videos
- I have a raspberry running with an official nginx docker image

**My Assumptions**

- nginx is a really powerful tool and provides all sorts of optimisation capabilities, but if I want to simply serve videos like the above, it would work kind "out-of-the-box"

**The Issue**

- The videos do not play at all
- When accessing the videos directly, there are two scenarios I encounter

  - a) HTTP 200 followed by one or more HTTP 206 Partials, and the video does not play, OR
    [image: Partial]
  - b) HTTP 200 followed by Cancelled request, and the video obviously does not play here either
    [image: Canceled]

**Furthermore**

- Multiple videos have been tested (default mobile output, VLC converted, HandBreak web optimized)

nginx (Default Configs provided by the official image)

```
html {
  sendfile on;
  tcp_nopush on;
  tcp_nodelay on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;
  types_hash_max_size 2048;
  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  gzip on;

  #SSL Settings
  #Logging Settings
}
```

In the mime.types, I do have video/mp4.

Static serving files

The videos are located in a folder, which is mounted as /usr/share/x

```
server {
  ...

  location / {
    # Default nginx files
  }

  location ~ \.mp4$ {
    # When I try to use this block, all video request end up being 404s
  }

  location /x/ {
    root /usr/share/;
  }
}
```

Given that this is a micro app, there are obviously other files being served, and they work fine. There is no issue with the locations and routing, only with the videos.

**Initial Request**

```
GET #### HTTP/1.1
Host: ####
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
sec-ch-ua: ####
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
DNT: 1
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: ####
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
Sec-Fetch-Site: none
Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate
Sec-Fetch-User: ?1
Sec-Fetch-Dest: document
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,hu;q=0.8,sk;q=0.7
sec-gpc: 1
```

**Initial Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.14.2
Date: Thu, 14 Jan 2021 19:50:01 GMT
Content-Type: video/mp4
Content-Length: 1620690
Last-Modified: Thu, 14 Jan 2021 19:05:25 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "600095f5-18bad2"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests
```

**Second Request** (Leading to the HTTP 206)

```
GET #### HTTP/1.1
Host: ####
Connection: keep-alive
sec-ch-ua: ####
DNT: 1
Accept-Encoding: identity;q=1, *;q=0
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
User-Agent: ####
Accept: */*
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-Fetch-Mode: no-cors
Sec-Fetch-Dest: video
Referer: ####
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,hu;q=0.8,sk;q=0.7
sec-gpc: 1
Range: bytes=0-
```

**The (sometimes cancelled) Partial Content**

```
HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content
Server: nginx/1.14.2
Date: Thu, 14 Jan 2021 20:03:20 GMT
Content-Type: video/mp4
Last-Modified: Thu, 14 Jan 2021 19:05:25 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "600095f5-18bad2"
Content-Range: bytes 0-1620689/1620690
Content-Length: 1620690
Content-Security-Policy: upgrade-insecure-requests
```

**Final Thoughts and Questions**

Im a Senior Front End developer. Far from an advanced Back End or DevOps knowledge, but I think I do well for myself. However, I have spent the better parts of the past 2-3 days trying to serve small videos from my Raspberry. Unsuccessfully.

1. Is this really an nginx configuration issue?
2. If so, what am I missing? How do I make this work?
3. If this is not nginx, what else could it be?

**UPDATE (1): cURL**

The file that I have chosen to test is 1620720 bytes. I tried to cURL it to see if I get back the same, working video.

`curl https://domain.tld/x/nope.mp4 --output ~/retrieved.mp4`

This new video is 1620690 bytes. 30 less then the original (gzip?) and it appears to be corrupted. I cannot play the video on my machine.

Checking the video in Firefox, they seem to get it right: [image: Corrupted]

Answer (score 1):

So. Apparently, a more hackathon-like approach, when you skip certain configuration steps, is not really beneficial. And when you want to do things quick and dirty, because time is of the essence, still you should set .mp4s to be treated as binaries in git. (Even better to use [LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/))

Comment: This comment actually helped me a lot ! My video file was not fully uploaded to git, or corrupted. That caused that it was not working. After spending several hours, I've removed it from git and manually uploaded to server AND IT WORKED.

Comment: Im glad my failure helped another! :sweat_smile: